# How to use non standard variables from extra field of Zotero?

Tags: csl

I have some custom variables that I have created; the variables are stored in the Extra field of Zotero using this format `myCustomVariable: myCustumVariableValue\n`
I would like to access them in the CSL file I have tried to use `<text variable="myCustomVariable"/>` it seems the correct way from the documentation, but it doesn’t work.
Is there any way I can access them and print them in the bibliography generated by Zotero? I could do a custom script in Python, but that would be reinventing CSL…